# How in Android to pass an object to new Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I'd greatly appreciate any thoughts on the following problem:
In Android I have my MainActivity, which creates and sets up a database handler class.
e.g.

```
public class DbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    //do db handling
}
```

Also, I've created my `OnClickListener`, which creates an `Intent` then startActivity's the Intent.

My question / problem is how to best pass the `DBHandler` into the new `Activity`.  I've thought about creating a global - and the risks of the thread restarting.  I can't quite work out how to parcel / serialize unless I create a wrapper - but still have the problem of passing the object in the "parcel"

I'm keen to understand how others have solved this??  Many thanks.

Comment: why not create a new instance of the DBHelper in the new activity?

Comment: try parcelable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelable%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable%29

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper you definitely do **not** want to parcel a class like this because you don't want to create 2 instances (one in each activity). This should be a singleton and available to all activities of the application.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks, I hadn't considered making this a singleton.  One of my concerns was multiple instances of the SQLite object, which this should address.

Comment: I have this exact logic, glad you asked this question and got a great answer from @karabara!

Answer (score 2):

As I know it is good practice to use only one instance of SQLiteOpenHelper, so create it as singleton and make accessible

```
public final class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    /**
     * instance.
     */
    private static DatabaseHelper instance;

    /**
     * @return instance.
     */
    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseHelper();
        }

        return instance;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will give this a go and I think it should solve the problem.

Comment: What about the context, don't you have to pass that in?